# CrudRepository Filter By One to Many Relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entity Customer and Order:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  .....
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
  private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<Order>();
  .....
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ........
    @ManyToOne()
    private Customer;
    ........
}
```

In the `CrudRepository` I want to find all customers who have no orders.
How can I write the @Query? Or how can I write the method in CrudRepository Interface?

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>{

  findBy ......

  @Query(".......")
  find.....

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `empty` keyword, that can be used with collection expressions (no need to join).

The JPQL query would be

```
select c from Customer c where c.orders is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

To query data that's not there you must use `left join`, something like this would do:

```java
@Query("select c from Customer as c left join c.orders as orders where orders is null")
```